# Put the information from MySQL into the textarea, without extra spaces?

Tags: php, html, textarea

My code is giving me a problem: When I save the information into the database, the formatting is being preserved, but when I put the information into the textarea, there are a lot of extra spaces.

Screenshoot: http://i1226.photobucket.com/albums/ee416/realodix/Photo%20Blog/description_zps8f9c858c.jpg

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="wbpl_add-edit.php?action=updateproduct&id=<?php echo $id ?>">
    <td>
    <table>

<?php
    $sql="select * from wbpl_product
          where kd_product='$id'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>

<tr>
<td width="120">Deskription</td>
<td width="350">
    <textarea name="product_deskripsi" rows="5" style="width: 512px;"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($rows['deskripsi']);?></textarea>
</td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>

<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>

    <td>
    <input class="btn" type="submit" name="tambah" value="Update" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan='2'><div id="form1_errorloc" style="color:red"></div></td>
</tr>

</table></td>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you trimming the description?

Comment: @Daryl Gill  
I tried to eliminate the spaces. Look at this picture http://i1226.photobucket.com/albums/ee416/realodix/Photo%20Blog/description_zps8f9c858c.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Each time you save that form, the whitespace after `<textarea>` will be prepended to the value, remove the spacing after `<textarea>` like the below:

```
<textarea name="product_deskripsi" rows="5" style="width: 512px;"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($rows['deskripsi']);?></textarea>
```

Comment: The code you gave, I already use. Thank you, but look at this http://s1226.photobucket.com/user/realodix/media/Photo%20Blog/before_after_zps504faa1b.jpg.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<textarea name="product_deskripsi" rows="5" style="width: 512px;">
```

add wrap

```
<textarea name="product_deskripsi" rows="5" wrap="virtual" style="width: 512px;">
```

You can use wrap: off, soft, hard, virtual or physical